# How to refresh all my IQueryable<EntityObject> type properties

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I have the need to refresh all my `IQueryable<EntityObject>` type properties.

I know that you can refresh a collection by:

```
someObjectContext.Refresh(System.Data.Objects.RefreshMode.StoreWins, someEntityObject);
```

But i am having trouble getting all the properties:

```
//Here i want to get all the propeties    
var iQueryablePropertiesList = ViewModel.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.GetType().BaseType is IQueryable<EntityObject>);

//Here i want to loop through all the properties and refresh them
foreach (var item in iQueryablePropertiesList)
{
    someObjectContext.Refresh(System.Data.Objects.RefreshMode.StoreWins, item.GetValue(this, null));
}

//Fire PropertyChanged for all properties
OnPropertyChanged(String.Empty);
```

`iQueryablePropertiesList` has no results.

The reason for this is that i need to refresh all my collections that are bound ComboBoxes.

So that being said:

1. Is this the correct way to refresh all my collections in my ViewModel?
2. If not, how should i approach my problem?
3. If it is, what do i need to add the the `LINQ` query to get my desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error on line:

```
x => x.GetType().BaseType is IQueryable<EntityObject>
```

`BaseType` is of type `Type` and it will never be `IQueryable<EntityObject>`. And `x.GetType()` also will return a type and in this case `PropertyInfo` always.

What you want to type is:

```
x => typeof(IQueryable<EntityObject>).IsAssignableForm(x.PropertyType)
```

this will check if `IQueryable<EntityObject>` is implemented by type that is your property.

```
public ThisType PropertyName{get;set;}
```

As to if this is a good way I don't think so reflection is always a problem and it will bite you sooner later. I would simply recreate model.

Comment: "reflection is always a problem and it will bite you sooner later". Can you provide any reference?

Comment: Is the `BaseType` thing even necessary? I guess it would be ok to ask for `IsAssignableForm(x.PropertyType)`.

Comment: @Clemens really no. I think this i 5 years experiences speaking. But don't get me wrong I use reflection where it is needed but I tend to do it the other way if possible. For this problem there is simple solution of creating viewmodel with the same method it was created in the first place. And yes `BaseClass` is not necessary.

Comment: @Rafal `x.PropertyType.BaseType` was null, but `x.PropertyType` worked.